# Inline images automatically link to larger version? Possible?

Tags: channel-images, image-path, inline-editing

Does anyone know a plugin/add-on or method to have images inserted inline (not custom field) into content by user automatically link to a larger version?

I have Channel Images installed and was surprised it had no means to do that. In their forum Dev Demon says doing so would be difficult, but it seems fairly simple to have an option to add an href to the image inserted and a dropdown to pick which processed version to link to—as a manual action or automatic (preferred).

We can’t even link manually to the CI images variations as they are stored in folders and the ee file manager can’t see them.

So, anyone done this?  Or am I just missing something in general? Seems a pretty common use case to have the user insert an image and easily link to a larger version (plugin or native method).

Thanks for your input.

Comment: I 'm not sure if understanding what you are looking for. You mentioned that you would like to show inline image and also mentioned that using Channel Images field type. With the channel images field type images can be uploaded/saved either from EE file directory or from the system. If you would like to show images as drop down from EE file directories then you can use File Module tag. Using file module, all the images of any directory can be populated. Take a reference from here http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/file/file_tag.html.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no i have not seen anything that does what you are looking for.

I understand your need - wanting to choose the thumbnail pre-processed file, and auto link it to the large pro-processed file - but i know of not automated addon that does this.

Typically yes, as you say i use a custom field, and then create it within the template. Often i do not use EE's pre-processed images but something like CE_IMAGE which processes and caches the various size images at template output. Hence very easily to set large and small.

I tend to agree that it would be tricky to modify a WYSIWYG editor field to do this. Not impossible, but would require deep connections to EE. I can only think you go manualy, upload thumb, upload large, and manually link in WYSIWYG editor.

N

Comment: Any thoughts on an a method of automatically getting an image to link to itself (href and img src same file)? The images are often a bit larger than displayed in browser since it's a responsive layout and that might be enough. Just grasping at straws... :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question completely, but are you using a WYSIWYG editor? Wygwam and Channel Images are integrated. So, conceivably, your user could insert the image desired via the Channel Images button, and then manually create a link to that same image. You could then use CE_Image's bulk tag to wrap around the Wygwam field so that the inline image is sized down to whatever thumb dimensions you prefer.

This seems a bit convoluted though, there may be ways to streamline it by playing around with multiple file upload folders or tying into CE_Image's hooks?

Comment: The user can't do a manual link because Channel Images stored every entry's images in a folder matching the entry id. The native EE file manager is incapable of showing/viewing subfolders. So you can't navigate to the entry subfolder to select the image and link to it manually (plus then the user would have to be aware of the entry id).

Comment: Channel Images stores the *sized* images it creates within subfolders I believe, but depending on how you set your upload location, (try main file upload) both EE and Wygwam will be able to access your original image upload. This works for me. If you want your image to link to itself can't you simply write some find and replace code, (or a plugin) that finds the orig image location and displays a thumb and larger size link in conjunction with CE_Image?